# Converting POS tags from TextBlob into Wordnet compatible inputs

Tags: python, tags, nlp, nltk, textblob

I'm using Python and nltk + Textblob for some text analysis. It's interesting that you can add a POS for wordnet to make your search for synonyms more specific, but unfortunately the tagging in both nltk and Textblob aren't "compatible" with the kind of input that wordnet expects for it's synset class.

**Example**
Wordnet.synsets() requires that the POS you give it is one of n,v,a,r, like so

```
wn.synsets("dog", POS="n,v,a,r")
```

But a standard POS tagging from upenn_treebank looks like

```
JJ, VBD, VBZ, etc.
```

So I'm looking for a good way to convert between the two.

Does anyone know of a good way to make this conversion happen, besides brute force?

Comment: Could you explain more about "aren't "compatible""?

Comment: Like give examples ...

Comment: The answer below is great - I've added some examples so people stumbling upon this post can get a feel for what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `textblob` is using the PennTreeBank (ptb) tagset, then just use the first character in the POS tag to map to the WN pos tag.

WN POS tagset includes 'a' = adjective/adverbs, 's'=satelite adjective, 'n' = nouns and 'v' = verbs.

try:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> text = 'this is a pos tagset in some foo bar paradigm'
>>> pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))
[('this', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('pos', 'NN'), ('tagset', 'NN'), ('in', 'IN'), ('some', 'DT'), ('foo', 'NN'), ('bar', 'NN'), ('paradigm', 'NN')]
>>> for tok, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)):
...     pos = pos[0].lower()
...     if pos in ['a', 'n', 'v']:
...             wn.synsets(tok, pos)
... 
[Synset('be.v.01'), Synset('be.v.02'), Synset('be.v.03'), Synset('exist.v.01'), Synset('be.v.05'), Synset('equal.v.01'), Synset('constitute.v.01'), Synset('be.v.08'), Synset('embody.v.02'), Synset('be.v.10'), Synset('be.v.11'), Synset('be.v.12'), Synset('cost.v.01')]
[Synset('polonium.n.01'), Synset('petty_officer.n.01'), Synset('po.n.03'), Synset('united_states_post_office.n.01')]
[]
[]
[Synset('barroom.n.01'), Synset('bar.n.02'), Synset('bar.n.03'), Synset('measure.n.07'), Synset('bar.n.05'), Synset('prevention.n.01'), Synset('bar.n.07'), Synset('bar.n.08'), Synset('legal_profession.n.01'), Synset('stripe.n.05'), Synset('cake.n.01'), Synset('browning_automatic_rifle.n.01'), Synset('bar.n.13'), Synset('bar.n.14'), Synset('bar.n.15')]
[Synset('paradigm.n.01'), Synset('prototype.n.01'), Synset('substitution_class.n.01'), Synset('paradigm.n.04')]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know if there was a better solution than to simply look at the first character, but It appears that's the best way. Thanks!

Comment: Would feel more comfortable if there's some reference to clarify that this is the best approximation available

Comment: Isn't this incorrect? PTB uses tags beginning JJ/RB for adjectives/verbs respectively. I've not tested it, but it seems that you'd have to do the following:

```ptb_wn_pos {
    'NN' : 'n',
    'JJ' : 'a',
    'RB' : 'a',
    'VB' : 'v'
} //
pos = pos[0:2] //
wn_pos = ptb_wn_pos[pos]
```

Edit: Apologies, I can't insert newlines for some reason, so imagine the // characters are newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function to convert [U Penn Treebank](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) tags to Wordnet tags (a,v,r,n):

```
Penn2Wn = lambda t='VB': t[0].lower() if t[0] in ('V','R','J') else 'n'
```

Just like in @alvas post, it takes the lower of the first character, if appropriate, or `'n'` as default. You can test it with:

```
Penn2Wn('VB')
Penn2Wn('PRP')
```